# Set of triple-primes satisfying a certain equation

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers

Is there a set of triple-primes satisfying the following equation?

$p_1p_2+p_2p_3+p_3p_1+p_1+p_2+p_3=2^β,p_1p_2p_3=2^α-1,α>β.$
I have checked the first 11 numbers that no one satisfy the above condition. It's easy to check that when all the prime numbers $p_i$ are in the form of $4k+3,$ then we have $p_i=2^{s_{i}}k_i+2^{s_{i}}−1$

Comment: In other words, $(p_1+1)(p_2+1)(p_3+1) = 2^\alpha + 2^\beta$.

Comment: Crossposted at [MSE](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1715675/set-of-triple-primes-satisfying-a-certain-equation/1715718#1715718).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is precisely one such triple of distinct primes
with $\alpha \leq 500$, namely $(3, 11, 31)$.

It would be a surprising coincidence if there are further
such triples for larger $\alpha$.

Comment: I've checked all $\alpha \leq 1200$ -- there are no new triples.

Comment: if we let $\alpha>\beta+1,gcd(2^{\alpha}-1,2^{\beta}+1)=1$.that means there almost no such primes satisfying the equation,at least for $\alpha \leq 1200$ is true.